# Is <img src="[srcpath]" alt=""> the same as <img src="[srcpath]" alt> when it comes to accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility, alt

```html
<img src="[srcpath]" alt="">
<img src="[srcpath]" alt>
```

That is to say:

Are those both considered null values for image `alt` text? Or must you ensure the `alt=""` is present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **should** use the `alt=""` attribute. Each example of the null alt attribute in the [specs for providing alternative text for an image](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#a-purely-decorative-image-that-doesn't-add-any-information) explicitly uses it. Here's [another resource on the empty `alt=""` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-alt-techniques/#secm3)

However.. if I were to look at the DOM inspector in Chrome and look at an `img` that had `alt=""` in the source code, I would see `<img src="[srcpath]" alt>`.

The [Failure Criterion F65](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140916/F65) in the WCAG 2.0 standards note that the presence of the `alt` attribute is sought. It does not clarify whether or not the alt attribute must be explicitly declared as empty (`alt=""`) for HTML5 standards, and as long as you're [using the HTML according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140916/H88), having `<img src="[srcpath]" alt>` would technically be considered accessible.

So in summary - **yes, they technically are the same** when it comes to accessibility, but I'm not one to derive from given instruction. By using `alt=""`, you are being aware of the purpose of the `alt` attribute, and keeping consistency in your alt techniques with respect to the HTML specifications.

Comment: Thanks @sjagr - My question stems from the fact that I was confused by my setting the alt attribute to "" via javascript was rendering in the chrome inspector as simply 'alt'.

Comment: @Abaxial As a dev, I'd say anything that Chrome does after I've done my job properly by using `alt=""` or setting an `alt` attribute to `alt=""` with Javascript is out of scope and on the burden of the user agent!

Answer (score 2):

Both have the **empty string** as value, so they are equivalent.

HTML5 defines that [attributes can be specified in four different ways](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/syntax.html#attributes-0), among them the "Empty attribute syntax":

> Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.